# hive : how to substract 1 second of a given timestamp

Tags: hive

I want to subtract 1 second from a given timestamp in hive. When I am trying to add 1 second to a given timestamp, then it is working good, but subtracting is not working good.

The below statement is giving me correct result for addition

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-06 01:00:00.000','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-06 01:00:00.000','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') + 1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

But for substraction I am not getting the correct result using below

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-06 01:00:00.000','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-06 01:00:00.000','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') - 1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

The subtract result which I am getting

```
2016-11-06 01:00:00.000 2016-11-06 01:59:59.000
```

But the expected result is

```
2016-11-06 01:00:00.000 2016-11-06 12:59:59.000
```

Comment: Add the results that you are getting to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "USA & Canada: DST Ends on Nov 6, 2016 ...
>
> Most of the United States, Canada, and Mexico's northern border cities
>   end Daylight Saving Time (DST) on Sunday, November 6, 2016.
>   DST ends on Sun, Nov
>   6, 2016
>
> Clocks will be set back 1 hour to standard time from 02:00 (2 am) to
>   01:00 (1 am), local time."
>
> https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/usa-canada-end-dst-2016.html

Comment: Question is can anyway we eliminate daylight saving part when adding or subtracting 1 second?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ref.rptg_end_ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') + (-1),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') ref.rptg_end_ts
```