# How to subtract a second from a date in Hive?

Tags: hive

Please tell me how can I subtract 1 second from the date in a Hive SQL query?
I want to make *SCD2* versioning.

I tried `Date_add()`, `datediff()`. They work with days. This doesn't fit.

Let's say there is

> '4/22/2023 4:32:21'

and should become

> '4/22/2023 4:32:20'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hive : how to substract 1 second of a given timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179780/hive-how-to-substract-1-second-of-a-given-timestamp)